# Guess the next number

Tags: number-sequence

Here is a sequence of numbers.  The goal is simply to provide the next 10 digit number in the series.

```
    6311433600
    3155760000 
    2840140800 
    2808604800 
    2805926400 
    2805321600 
    2805235200
    ??????????
```

Hint:

> Time is of the essence

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 2805231600

My process:

> My first thought was to figure out the difference between each successive number, assuming that this was a sequence. When I saw that the difference of the last two was 86400, which I know to be the number of seconds in a day, I did a little googling and found that the other differences corresponded to successively larger units of time- a week, a 31-day month, etc. So the next number should be smaller by an hour, or 3600 seconds.

Comment: The differences are, in order: 100 years, 10 years, 1 year, 1 month, 1 week, 1 day.